# Finding out the URL called by an ajax action

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have to scrape [this page](http://www.flipkart.com/computers/components/ram-20214?_l=m56QC%20tQahyMi46nTirnSA--&_r=11FxOYiYfpMxmANj4kGJzg--&_pop=flyout) using php curl. In this when the user scrolls down , more items are loaded using ajax . Can I call the URL that the ajax script is calling ? If so, then how do I figure the URL out ? I know a bit of ajax, but the code there is kind of complex for me. 
Here is the relevant js code [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6DM32c1U)

Alternatively can someone suggest an alternative method of scraping that page? PS : I doing this for good cause.

Edit: I figured it out. Live http headers. QUestion can be closed. downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You can monitor requests and what URLs they are sent to using network modules like Firebug for Firefox. Chrome has it built in and so does IE9 I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for that. Switch to the Console-Tab and then make the page make the AJAX-request.

This is what should see after scrolling to the bottom of the page: http://www.flipkart.com/computers/components/ram-20214?_l=m56QC%20tQahyMi46nTirnSA--&_r=11FxOYiYfpMxmANj4kGJzg--&_pop=flyout&response-type=json&inf-start=20

and if you scroll further: http://www.flipkart.com/computers/components/ram-20214?_l=m56QC%20tQahyMi46nTirnSA--&_r=11FxOYiYfpMxmANj4kGJzg--&_pop=flyout&response-type=json&inf-start=40

The tokens seem to always remain the same: `_l=m56QC%20tQahyMi46nTirnSA--` and `_r=11FxOYiYfpMxmANj4kGJzg--`, so does the `_pop`-parameter: `_pop=flyout`  So let's have a look at the other parameters:

This one was for the main page:

```
//no additional parameters...
```

this one for the first 'reload':

```
&response-type=json&inf-start=20
```

and this one for the second 'reload':

```
&response-type=json&inf-start=40
```

So, appearently you just have to append `&response-type=json&inf-start=$offset` to your initial URI to get the results in JSON-format. You can also see the contents in FireBug which should make it very easy to work with them.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]